# Issue with CSS width and views columns and headers

Tags: xpages

I have some CSS I am applying to a view header and view column.

Here is a sample

```
.viewHeaderName {
width:235px;
background-color:rgb(192,192,192);
color:rgb(0,0,0);
font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;
font-size:10t;
font-weight:bold;
text-align:left;
}

.viewColumnName {

font-family:Trebuchet MS,sans-serif;
font-size:9pt;      

}
```

Basically I am trying to set the width of the column to what I want. I don't want the text in the header or in the column to wrap.   This works perfectly for categorized views for all the columns.

But for simple sorted views, the header is being offset to the right from the text in the column several characters.

If I remove the width parameter in the CSS then everything lines up fine but I don't get the width I want.

Comment: a pcture of the problem would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use td/th nowrap attribute described here

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_nowrap.asp

**or**

use white-space element in css described here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

white-space:nowrap;