# controlling the width of a column in an xpages viewpanel

Tags: html, css, xpages

We are running Domino 8.5.3 (planning to go to 9 asap).  I have an application that consists of viewpanels with searches.  My viewpanel displays a lot of columns and I would like to have some control over the size of the individual columns.  I have been everywhere and tried setting several different column styles using a variety of inline and css techniques, but I can't seem to override whatever the "xspTextViewColumn" is doing.
Here are some of the website pages that I have consulted:
http://blog.hughesconnect.com/?p=138
[Issue with CSS width and views columns and headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502838/issue-with-css-width-and-views-columns-and-headers)
http://iswwwup.com/t/df2dfb59c014/how-can-i-left-align-the-extra-columns-in-an-xpages-data-view.html
I do not have access to dojo or extension libraries.
Thanks.
---Lisa&

Comment: Well - actually nothing really worked consistently.  I examined the html output by using the F12 option in the IE browser.  There are two classes automatically assigned to the row:  <td class="xspColumnViewStart or xspColumnViewMiddle"  followed by <span class =xspTextViewColumn.  I think there are some sizing parameters in those classes that are difficult to override.

Comment: My best results were obtained when I set the viewPanel to a width of 100% and then set each column to a percentage of 100.  One of the reasons that I was seeing inconsistencies was that my IE defaults to a zoom of 125%.  When I switch to a zoom of 100%, everything looks much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add width:100px; to the style property of the view column you want to adjust. By using the style property it will render as a style attribute in the HTML which takes precedence over any CSS rules contained in classes.

Comment: Thanks - I will green check your answer.  I added the following to my stylesheet:  .colrestraint {
 width: 100px;
} and associated the style with the column by referencing the class in the style section of the properties for the column.  It is not completely perfect (some of the columns on the right do not seem to be listening - especially in IE), but things look much cleaner.

Comment: One column in particular is very stubborn - in both ie and chrome.

Comment: Try putting the viewpanel inside a panel container. Then set the style of the panel container to the sum of all the widths of the view panel columns. For example if you have 3 columns each 100px then make the panel width 300px.

Comment: To have more grip on the sizes of the columns,  you could try setting table-layout: fixed